# Examples of rings with an infinite chain of principal ideals whose union is not principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was struggling for a few days to prove that *the union of an infinite ascending chain of principal ideals is a principal ideal*. It occurred to me a few minutes ago that this claim is actually false.

**What are some example rings with infinite ascending chains of principal ideals that are not principal? I found one by adjoining iterated square roots of two, but I'm wondering if there are any simpler rings that can demonstrate this.**

---

Let $f(n) = (2)^{(1/2^n)}$, i.e. $f(1) = \sqrt{2}$ and $f(1+n) = \sqrt{f(n)}$.

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[f(\mathbb{N})]$ and the ideal $(f(\mathbb{N})) = (f(1), f(2), \cdots)$ .

By a simple norm argument, $(f(\mathbb{N}))$ is not the trivial ideal.

$(f(\mathbb{N}))$ is the union of the chain $(f(1)) \subset (f(2)) \subset \cdots$.

$(f(\mathbb{N}))$ is also not principal, as I will show.

Every number in $R$ has the form $(a) 2^d $ where $a$ is odd and $d$ is a non-negative dyadic rational.

$$(a)2^d * (b) 2^e = (ab) 2^{(d + e)}$$

If $d$ has the form $\frac{p}{2^n}$, then no positive dyadic rational can be added to produce $\frac{p}{2^{(n+1)}}$.

Therefore, if the generator of $(f(\mathbb{N}))$ has the form $(a)2^{p/2^n}$, then $f(n+1) = (2)^{1/2^{n+1}}$ is not in the ideal, which is a contradiction.

Comment: The ring of algebraic integers is a Bezout domain, so any finitely generated ideal is principal. However, it contains ideals that are not finitely generated. Take one such ideal, and express it as a countable increasing union of principals ideals. E.g., the ideal generated by all $2^{1/n}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not finitely generated, but it is equal to the union of the principal ideals $I_m = (2^{1/1},2^{1/2},\ldots,2^{1/m})$, $m=1,2,\ldots$

Comment: More generally, any non-Noetherian Bezout domain will do. [Wikipedia has several examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain), like the ring of entire functions, and non-Noetherian valuation rings,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin those comments are really good. Do you want to make them an answer?

Comment: @rschwieb I think you gave a link to a local instance of your website. https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=67l&L=64l

Comment: @GregNisbet Ha, yes, I happened to be developing on it and had too many tabs open. I'll redo my comment: thanks

Comment: [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=67l&L=64l) for non-Noetherian commutative Bezout rings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Getting this out of unanswered limbo*

---

You could use $R=\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}F_2$. This ring is Bezout, and in fact the f.g. ideals are even summands.

The ideal $I=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb N}F_2$ is a countable union of principal ideals of the form $\bigoplus_{i=0}^nF_2$

---

There is also $R=\mathbb Z+x\mathbb Q[x]$ (also Bezout.) The ideal $x\mathbb Q[x]$ is not f.g. To generate everything in $x\mathbb Q$ you only have generators that begin with $xq_i+\cdots$ and when you multiply with ring elements, they will only help out with integers. Since $\mathbb Q$ isn't f.g. as a $\mathbb Z$ module, you can't get all of $x\mathbb Q$ with multiples of finitely many elements of $x\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=67l&L=88l) for non-Noetherian Bezout rings, all of which would work.